# How to create camera view in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How can I just display a live feed of the rear camera in Objective-C? What do I need to add to my storyboard and what do I need to add to my ViewController? Any examples would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use AVFoundation, specifically look at AVCaptureSession, AVCaptureDeviceInput, which you can use in order to get access to the cameras and look into AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer which will allow you to draw the camera input to the screen

**EDIT :**

There's a step by step tutorial in Obj-C about it :

https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/